# pdf file not shown in polymer pdf element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, pdf.js

If i add the following element in my code, everything works correctly, except the pdf doesn't show up. Instead a white square minimizes to a small dot on the left.
It would be great if someone could help me out, thanks in advance. 
https://github.com/streetturtle/pdf-element

```
<dom-module id="split-view">
 <template>
   <style>
   </style>
    <pdf-element src="example.pdf"  downloadable height="700" show file-name enable-text-selection show-spinner></pdf-element>
 </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'split-view',
      });
    })();
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: You would have to post some code demonstrating the issue. You could also inspect the element in the browser developer tools and see if if is a result of CSS styling.

Comment: Make sure you've imported `pdf-element.html` (presumably from `bower_components`) and that `example.pdf` is accessible. As an aside (unrelated to your immediate problem), `show file-name` should be `show-file-name`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @tony19 mentioned, **example.pdf** should be accessible (the path to the file is right). To check that have a look the the console of the browser (in Developer Tools, <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome), if file is not accessible you would have a 404 error there.

And also in case you have problems with some project from github, create an issue there ([github.com/streetturtle/pdf-element/issues](https://github.com/streetturtle/pdf-element/issues)), this way the owner of the project would see it right away.